# Как сверить 2 массива и удалить одинаковые значения?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Предположим  есть ассоциативный массив `

```
a = {
    "a": "17",
    "b": "1",
    "d": "3",
    "v": "10",
    "e": "4",
    "f": "9"
}
```

и есть второй массив

```
b = {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "3",
    "d": "4",
    "v": "5",
    "e": "6",
    "f": "7"
}
```

Как мне узнать какие значения есть в ассоциативном массиве a и нет в массиве b ? или как узнать какие значения есть в массиве b и нет в массиве a .

То есть например мы сравниваем ассоциативный  массив `a` c `b`, и в результате сравнение мы должны узнать что в ассоциативном массиве a есть значения `17, 10, 9` которых нет в ассоциативном  массиве `b`. Или же мы сравниваем `b` c `a` , и в результате сравнения мы должны узнать что в ассоциативном  массиве `b` есть `5, 6, 7` которых нет в ассоциативном массиве `a`.

нужно узнать уникальные значения значений.

Как делать подобные сравнения ?

Comment: Начать стоит с того, что это у вас вообще не массивы, а словари / ассоциативные карты. Прочитайте о том и другом, а после уточните вопрос: вы хотите уникальные значения ключей или значений?

Comment: @ Nick Volynkin, исправил вопрос. Нужно узнать уникальные значения значений. То есть в ассоциативном массиве a есть значения 17, 10 9 - которых нет в B, и наоборот какие значения есть в B которых нет в A

Comment: хорошо, так стало конкретнее. В JS ведь есть множества (set)? Общий алгоритм может быть таким: переберите оба словаря, вытащите значения в два соответствующих множества, а потом производите над ними обычные операции алгебры множеств (тоже должны быть реализованы в JS).

Comment: @Dementiy1999 Опять непонятно. То есть там где `ключ_А != ключ_B` или `ключ_А != ключ_B и значение_А != значение_B` или только где `значение_А != значение_B`

Comment: Подправил форматирование. Посмотрите, насколько сразу стало понятнее. Теперь видно несоответствие, о котором Алексей говорит.

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский, смотрите эту проблему я изначально решал смерджив два этих массива убрав полностью  повторяющиеся элементы оставив ток уникальные. То теперь стала задача  узнать в каком именно из массивов есть те или иные уникальные элементы. Вот это не получается...

Comment: @ Nick Volynkin, смотрите если объединить два этих массива а потом оставить ток уникальные значения то получится  {17, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7}. Но ток мы тогда не узнаем и с какого именно массива уникальные элементы . Как это узнать ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мне кажется, ничего сложного. Нужно делать ровно так, как вы описали. Нас интересуют только значения, соответственно отбрасываем ключи:

```
var a_values = Object.keys(a).map(function(key){
    return a[key];
});

var b_values = Object.keys(b).map(function(key){
    return b[key];
});
```

После чего ищем "уникальные" для какого-либо массива:

```
var res = [];

for (var a_key in a_values) {
    if (b_values.indexOf(a_values[a_key]) == -1) {
        res.push(a_values[a_key]);
    }
}
```

Рабочий пример: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejbszs0v/1/)

Comment: Спасибо большое все работает

Answer (score 3):

Сначала давайте создадим функцию, которая "поменяет местами" ключи объекта с значениями:

```
function reMap(obj)
 {
   var ret={};
   for(var k in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) ret[obj[k]]=k;
   return ret;
 }
```

После этого мы можем легко преобразовать наши объекты (Да, это именно объекты, а не массивы) к спискам значений, которые собственно и сравним:

```
function getUnique(obj1,obj2)
 {
  var ret=[];
  for(var k in obj1)
   {
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(k) && ! obj2.hasOwnProperty(k)) ret.push(k);
   }
  return ret;
 }

var a1=reMap(a);
var b1=reMap(b);

getUnique(a1,b1);
getUnique(b1,a1)
```

Comment: Если два ключа с одинаковыми значениями, то что будет с коллизиями при перемене мест?

Comment: @NickVolynkin В объекте окажется в качестве значения второй ключ. Т.е. особо ничего страшного. Я в начале вообще хотел посчитать заодно кол-во значений, но оно чуть более громоздким выходило. И в принципе можно было просто массивы значений получить. В итоге плюсанул второй ответ, в отличие от меня он знает JS :)

Comment: @Mike: Ок, про коллизии понял. Ещё вопрос: неужели в JS не реализована алгебра множеств и нужно вручную перебирать их во вложенном цикле?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я о таком не слышал. И в принципе в списке доступных функций у Object и array сейчас ничего интересного не нашел. Но я явно не последняя инстанция, я в JS примерно "читаю со словарем". Вот пока ответ писал, узнал у гугла как красиво `for` по объекту написать :)

Comment: @Mike: начал писать алгоритмический ответ, увяз на том что js вообще не знаю, а без кода как-то неудобно публиковать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну JS он вообще особенный. Ассоциативных массивов в нем нет. Их заменяют объекты. Потому как в объекты произвольные свойства можно добавлять на лету. Вот в те же `a и b` помимо данных можно было еще и методы запихать :) Есть обычные массивы, хотя они то же объекты, только у них прототип другой. Ну в общем все весело в JS :) Я сейчас его плохо знаю, при том что прилично читал по нему. JS один из тех языков в которые я вообще не мог въехать просто смотря чужой код. Поэтому вот этот мой ответ "в процедурном стиле" новичкам в JS явно понятнее, чем те, крутые `map` :)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ конечно рабочий, но зачем создавать a_values когда в нем все равно пробегаетесь через for ... in?

Нам нужны значения только одного объекта, что бы проводить сравнение.

```
function diff(a, b) {
  var b_values = [],
      res      = [];

  for (var key in b) {
    b_values.push(b[key]);
  }

  for (var key in a) {
    if (b_values.indexOf(a[key]) === -1) {
      res.push(a[key]);
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```